# Ошибка в ходе установки kubernetes в linux

Tags: linux, установка, kubernetes

На одном из этапов установки kubernetes в linux после ввода команды:

```
vim  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

выдает ошибку:

```
Command 'vim ' not found, did you mean:

  command 'vim' from deb vim (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5)
  command 'vim' from deb vim-tiny (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5)
  command 'vim' from deb neovim (0.4.3-3)
  command 'vim' from deb vim-athena (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5)
  command 'vim' from deb vim-gtk3 (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5)
  command 'vim' from deb vim-nox (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5)

Try: apt install <deb name>
```

Попытки (apt install deb vim, apt install vim и тд) выдают ошибки, например:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package deb
```

Следующим пунктом должно быть прописывание в файле kubernetes.list :

```
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
```

Но остановился на предыдущем шаге (застрял на команде   vim  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list).

Comment: Не понятно что у вас вызвало проблемы: вам прям написали, что у вас не установлен vim. Ваша попытка установки с помощью команды `apt install deb vim` не верна, необходимо использовать `apt install vim`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать другой редактор. Например

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

Чтобы установить vim, используйте

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: да, я уже так и сделал. продолжаю установку дальше.

Comment: просто всегда пользовался nano, а тут какой-то vim и сбило с толку. но раз надо прописать что-то в kubernetes.list, то сделал с nano.